# Using glob mime types in mimeapps.list for use with xdg-open?

Tags: xdg-open

With `xdg-open` I would like to open all image files with `shotwell`, even risking that it may complain about files types it does not know about.

I added

```
[Default Applications]
image/png=shotwell.desktop
```

to `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and could now go on to add more lines for all image formats I could think of. But this can be tedious.

I tried already to use

```
image/*=shotwell.desktop
```

but this does not work. Is there a way to define a default for all image files without explicitly listing them all?

Answer (score 1):

I also naively assumed globbing would work but after a great deal of searching have found no evidence that it or a similar mechanism is available for catching all files of a certain *type* (e.g. image) rather than *subtype* (image/png).

Fortunately, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) maintains a [list of standard MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) which you can use to fill your `mimeapps.list`. Personally, I found it convenient to just copy the relevant lines from my distribution's default list (which I found at `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`) and change the desktop entries I wanted to.